# SwiftUI Interation with Widget on iOS 14

Tags: swiftui, widget, ios14, widgetkit

I'm looking for a way to add interaction with widgets on iOS 14, but the results are all on iOS 17. Can anyone who has handled widget manipulation on iOS 14 give me a reference?

Comment: Pre iOS 17 all you have is “tappable areas” the Widget Code Along can walk you through it.